# Haskell parallel search with early abort

Tags: haskell, search, parallel-processing

I'd like to search through a list, testing each element for property X and then return when an element with property X is found.

This list is very large and would benefit from parallelism, but the cost of the spark is rather high relative to the compute time. `parListChunk` would be great, but then it must search through the entire list.

Is there some way I can write something like `parListChunk` but with early abort?

This is the naive search code:

```
hasPropertyX :: Object -> Bool

anyObjectHasPropertyX :: [Object] -> Bool
anyObjectHasPropertyX [] = False
anyObjectHasPropertyX l
| hasPropertyX (head l) == True = True
| otherwise = anyObjectHasPropertyX (tail l)
```

and this is my first attempt at parallelism:

```
anyObjectHasPropertyXPar [] = False
anyObjectHasPropertyXPar [a] = hasPropertyX a
anyObjectHasPropertyXPar (a:b:rest) = runEval $ do c1 <- rpar (force (hasPropertyX a))
                                                   c2 <- rpar (force (hasPropertyX b))
                                                   rseq c1
                                                   rseq c2
                                                   if (c1 == True) || (c2 == True) then return True else return (anyObjectHasPropertyXPar rest)
```

This does run slightly faster than the naive code (even with `-N1`, oddly enough), but not by much (it helps a little by extending the number of parallel computations). I believe it's not benefitting much because it has to spark one thread for each element in the list.

Is there an approach similar to `parListChunk` that will only spark n threads and that allows for an early abort?

Edit: I'm having problems thinking about this because it seems that I would need to monitor the return value of all the threads. If I omit the `rseq`'s and have something like

```
if (c1 == True) || (c2 == True) then ...
```

Is the runtime environment intelligent enough to monitor both threads and continue when either one of them returns?

Comment: You are using `Eval` incorrectly - you shouldn't `runEval` at every cons of the list. I doubt this would give any performance gain in general, unless computing `hasPropertyX` is absurdly expensive and the list is comparatively short. Have you benchmarked the version using `parListChunk`? The hypothesis "it must search through the entire list" might be valid but you should test it. Anyways, I'm guessing something like `or . parMap return hasPropertyX` would work just fine (or `or . parMap (parListChunk k return) hasPropertyX` for some `k`).

Comment: Thanks! The first snippet you listed (`or . parMap return hasPropertyX`) works as listed, but gets slower with each processor core that I add. The second one  (`or . parMap (parListChunk 2 return) hasPropertyX`) errors as listed, and I'm having a problem figuring it out:     `• Couldn't match type ‘[a0]’ with ‘Bool’
      Expected type: [Object] -> [Bool]
        Actual type: [Object] -> [[a0]]`

Comment: I fixed the error with  `or . withStrategy (parListChunk 2 return) . map hasPropertyX`. It still gets slower with each processor added. I don't feel like it's interrupting the other threads when a match is found, but I'm not sure how to test this.

Comment: (Right, sorry about that, I didn't typecheck the code except in my head). It doesn't make sense to talk about interrupting a spark (as opposed to interrupting a thread started with e.g. `forkIO` by throwing an exception to it) because a spark is internal to the runtime. If you have an expression like `x || y` then as soon as `x` evaluates to `True`, `x || y` also evaluates to `True`. Then the spark which was forked to evaluate `y` will be garbage collected. That happens on the next GC cycle, so you need to pick a chunk size which works will with the frequency of GC (by experimentation!).

Comment: ... You almost certainly want a chunk size in the thousands or tens of thousand (you say "list is very large"!) - the cost of splitting the list into chunks of 2 and trying to spark a thread to process two elements will probably dominate the running time compared to evaluating `propertyX`. Also, it may be that you have to fold each sparked chunk individually, then fold the results from each spark sequentially - something like `or . map or . withStrategy .. . map propertyX` (again, untested).

Comment: How is this very large list getting populated? I wonder if a list is the best type... Maybe Vector would be better? Would then mean you can split the vector up without traversing it and keeping better data locality for each thread?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to have much luck using `Control.Parallel.Strategies`.  A key feature of this module is that it expresses "deterministic parallelism" such that the result of the program is unaffected by the parallel evaluation.  The problem you've described is fundamentally non-deterministic because threads are racing to find the *first* match.

**Update:**  I see now that you're only returning `True` if the element is found, so the desired behavior *is* technically deterministic.  So, perhaps there is a way to trick the `Strategies` module into working.  Still, the implementation below seems to meet the requirements.

Here's an implementation of a parallel find `parFind` that runs in the IO monad using `Control.Concurrent` primitives and seems to do what you want.  Two `MVars` are used:  `runningV` keeps count of how many threads are still running to allow the last thread standing to detect search failure; and `resultV` is used to return `Just` the result or `Nothing` when search failure is detected by that last thread.  Note that it is unlikely to perform better than a single-threaded implementation unless the test (your `hasPropertyX` above) is substantially more work than the list traversal, unlike this toy example.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import Data.List
import System.Environment

-- Thin a list to every `n`th element starting with index `i`
thin :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
thin i n = unfoldr step . drop i
  where step [] = Nothing
        step (y:ys) = Just (y, drop (n-1) ys)

-- Use `n` parallel threads to find first element of `xs` satisfying `f`
parFind :: Int -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> IO (Maybe a)
parFind n f xs = do
  resultV <- newEmptyMVar
  runningV <- newMVar n
  comparisonsV <- newMVar 0
  threads <- forM [0..n-1] $ \i -> forkIO $ do
    case find f (thin i n xs) of
      Just x -> void (tryPutMVar resultV (Just x))
      Nothing -> do m <- takeMVar runningV
                    if m == 1
                      then void (tryPutMVar resultV Nothing)
                      else putMVar runningV (m-1)
  result <- readMVar resultV
  mapM_ killThread threads
  return result

myList :: [Int]
myList = [1..1000000000]

-- Use `n` threads to find first element equal to `y` in `myList`
run :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
run n y = do x <- parFind n (== y) myList
             print x

-- e.g.,  stack ghc -- -O2 -threaded SearchList.hs
--        time ./SearchList +RTS -N4 -RTS 4 12345  # find 12345 using 4 threads -> 0.018s
--        time ./SearchList +RTS -N4 -RTS 4 -1     # full search w/o match -> 6.7s
main :: IO ()
main = do [n,y] <- getArgs
          run (read n) (read y)
```

Also, note that this version runs the threads on interleaved sublists rather than dividing the main list up into consecutive chunks.  I did it this way because (1) it was easier to demonstrate that "early" elements were found quickly; and (2) my huge list means that memory usage can explode if the whole list needs to be kept in memory.

In fact, this example is a bit of a performance time bomb -- its memory usage is nondeterministic and can probably explode if one thread falls way behind so that a substantial portion of the whole list needs to be kept in memory.

In a real world example where the whole list *is* probably being kept in memory and the property test is expensive, you may find that breaking the list into chunks is faster.